# $\int_0^1 \lvert f_n(t,x) \rvert^2 dx \leq \frac{2}{t}$ and $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \lvert f_n(t,x) \rvert^2 dxdt \leq M$ leads to uniform bound over $t$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $\{f_n(t,x) :[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R} \}$ be a sequence of continuous functions.

Let us assume that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \lvert f_n(t,x) \rvert^2 dx \leq \frac{2}{t}
\end{equation}
for all $0<t \leq 1$ and and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If we additionally assume that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \lvert f_n(t,x) \rvert^2 dxdt \leq M
\end{equation}
for some fixed constant $M>0$, then is it possible to deduce that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \lvert f_n(t,x) \rvert^2 dx \leq C
\end{equation}
for some fixed $C>0$ for all $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I somehow suspect that this is true, but cannot justify my guess..Could anyone please help me?

Edit : I think I need to add more conditions. Suppose further that $f_n(0,x)=f(x)$ for some given continuous function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert^2 dx  =M.
\end{equation}

Then, does it make any difference?

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but if it does I would like to point out that if the integral respect to x is anything like 1/sqrt(t) then while it still satisfies 1/sqrt(t) < 2/t it is not bounded by any finite C, and the integral of 1/sqrt(t) over [0,1] is still finite.

Comment: Oh I see...thank you for your insight..

Comment: I added one more condition.

Comment: It's probably used in the context you're working with, but in this question specifically I don't see the usefulness of looking at a sequence here, since there is no taking-the-limit nor any dependence on $n$ or between the different functions.

Comment: I tried to extract out only what I was curious about...Yes, I have to deal with the limit of the sequence in the end. So, I am concerned about the uniform bound with respect to $t$ of the $L^2$ norm on $x$ variable...Could you please help?

Comment: Oh , I found a counterexample myself by setting $f_n(x,t)=f(x)g_n(t)$....Thank you for your help anyway..